# Why did nobody use Reaper Death Seal during the Fourth Great Ninja War?

Tags: naruto

Why didn't the Reaper Death Seal appear during the Fourth Great Ninja War? If it was used on Madara or Obito, it would have ended the war easily, right?

Comment: Using the reaper death seal during the 4th Ninja War would'nt have guaranteed to make the war easier. Hiruzen used this against Orochimarau, but yet - while immobilized - survived

Comment: @Wondercricket Not to mention that there are only two people who use this and both are dead. I am not sure how a temporarily resurrected ninja who's already dead can exchange his soul again.

Comment: @W.Are That's a good question. Even I'm desperate to know the answer for that.

Answer (score 5):

**Because there are only two known users of the Dead Demon Consuming Seal (also called as Sealing Jutsu: Reaper Death Seal): Hiruzen Sarutobi and Minato Namikaze, and the jutsu can be countered.**

While something like this could probably be done:

- Use Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation to resurrect Minato and Sarutobi
- They, then, use Dead Demon Consuming Seal on Madara
- If successful and if the user desires it, release Minato and Sarutobi using Dead Demon Consuming Seal: Release so they can break free from the Shinigami and can go the afterlife

This is on the assumption that:

- Reincarnated ninjas are not subject to limitations.
- Madara cannot counter the Dead Demon Consuming Seal.
- Only certain people can be broken free from Dead Demon Consuming Seal: Release (assuming that the user would want to release Minato and Sarutobi again).

However, we know that:

- **There are also limitations to reincarnated people** as seen [here](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Attributes), and while it was not shown in the manga, it may or may not be possible that reincarnated ninja cannot use Dead Demon Consuming Seal. This begs the question: **Can a ninja who already offered up his/her soul to the Shinigami offer it again?** There is no precedent to something like this in the manga so I am not sure we would know this any time soon, although personally, I believe the answer to this is a 'no' since Kishimoto did not let us see the characters attempting this.
- Dead Demon Consuming Seal can be countered, as seen during Orochimaru and Sarutobi's fight. It's quite impossible that Madara would also not be able to do the same. **This, to me, is probably one of the biggest reason why we didn't get to see it.** A villain who's easily defeated by this do not make up for a good plot since this would have resulted to a much shorter and anticlimactic ending.
- Cutting open the stomach of the Shinigami [releases any souls inside of it](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Demon_Consuming_Seal). This would mean that Minato, Sarutobi and Madara would have to be sealed forever inside the Shinigami. You might argue that they would probably agree to this plan **but that would have resulted to a less happy ending to the *Naruto* we know.**

Answer (score 0):

Like said above they can not do that. Because one of the conditions that must be done to use Reaper Death Seal is to offer your soul to Shinigami (Reaper). So you are dead so you can not do that because like we see they have their bodies tied on that Reaper to offer him their life and soul. And other thing  even if this could happen they were in Reaper once and I do not think it would accept their sacrifice once again.

Answer (score 0):

Minato and Hiruzen are the only known shinobi to ever know how to use Reaper Death Seal. Plus, according to many sources, the Reaper Death Seal requires sacrificing your OWN SOUL in order to seal others. It's stated in the original Naruto series when Hiruzen seals Orochimaru's arms and doesn't dodge his blade. What I'm about to say is nothing but a theory. Reaper Death Seal requires your OWN SOUL, but the Edo Tensei Hokage need a living sacrifice to be revived. So the White Zetsu were used. So I speculate that since they didn't possess THEIR soul, but rather, White Zetsu's, the Reaper Death Seal wouldn't work because you'd be sacrificing a soul other than yours.